# Error using generic return type (incompatible types: cannot be converted to T)

Tags: java, generics, signature

```
public class Main{
    private MyQueue queue = null;
    private MyStack stack = null;
    private MyList list = null;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }
    
    public void run(){
        // only one data structure is not null.
        // for example, let's suppose that it's queue
        this.queue = new MyQueue();
        
        int intToAdd = 6;   // I want to add this number
        this.selectStruct().insert(intToAdd);       // I want to invoke the "insert" method of the current data structure in use
    }
    
    private <T> T selectStruct(){       // this should check with data structure is in use (so which of them is not null) and then return the reference
        if (this.queue!=null){
            return this.queue;
        }
        if (this.stack!=null){
            return this.stack;
        }
        if (this.list!=null){
            return this.list;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this method called `selectStruct` to select the current data structure in use and return the reference. And from this reference then call `insert` that invokes the correct insert method of the correct class.

The problem is that I have several errors. I have never used generics, so I'm a bit confused.

```
$ javac Main.java
Main.java:22: error: incompatible types: MyQueue cannot be converted to T
                        return this.queue;
                                   ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>selectStruct()
Main.java:25: error: incompatible types: MyStack cannot be converted to T
                        return this.stack;
                                   ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>selectStruct()
Main.java:28: error: incompatible types: MyList cannot be converted to T
                        return this.list;
                                   ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>selectStruct()
Main.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                this.selectStruct().insert(intToAdd);
                                   ^
  symbol:   method insert(int)
  location: class Object
4 errors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `MyQueue`, `MyStack`, and `MyList` implement the same interface containing the methods you want all your data structures to implement, e.g:

```
public interface IDataStructure {
    void insert(int intToAdd);
}
```

Your classes should then look like this:

```
public class MyQueue implements IDataStructure{

    @Override
    public void insert(int intToAdd) {
        // TODO 
    }

}

public class MyStack implements IDataStructure{

    @Override
    public void insert(int intToAdd) {
        // TODO 
    }

}

public class MyList implements IDataStructure{

    @Override
    public void insert(int intToAdd) {
        // TODO 
    }

}
```

Finally, you can modify your `selectStruct()` method to return an IDataStructure:

```
private IDataStructure selectStruct() {
    if (this.queue != null) {
        return this.queue;
    }
    if (this.stack != null) {
        return this.stack;
    }
    if (this.list != null) {
        return this.list;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :)

since MyQueue, MyStack and MyList already implements some certain interfaces, I've thought that instead of creating an IDataStructure interface, to create instead an IDataStructure abstract class that implements the SAME interfaces (they are the same for each data structure). So after this, instead of writing implements inside MyQueue, MyStack and MyList, I just write "extends IDataStructure" and the work is done. I've done it and it works, but I wanted to know if it was good for object oriented programming.

Comment: @Sperly Just to get it right: All your data structures need to implement multiple interfaces to function as data structures? Then your choice of an abstract class that implements those interfaces is a very good one. To give an example why: imagine you decide that a data structure needs a different specific logic, or you decide to remove an interface. In these cases, you need to change all the concrete classes. In your case, most of the changes will be in your abstract class. So yes, I think your idea is good.

Comment: But please think of another name for it. The `I` in `IDataStructure` stands for interface. You need something like `AbstractDataStructure`. But of course this naming depends on the convention you have to follow.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a method with a type parameter T (like `private <T> T selectStruct()`), you are saying that the user of this method can choose any type they want to use this method.

So in the body of `selectStruct`, you don't know which type the caller will use, and of course you can not return any specific type. That's why your every return clause like `return this.queue;` will produce an error.

Comment: thanks for answer. so there's not any way to fix this issue?

Comment: You should change the way you use generic. @Michael Chatiskatzi 's answer has show you how to do it. I just tell you why the way you use it it's not supported.

Comment: yeah I know, I was just curious on how could I do that with generics.